# Bootstrap4 Responsive Table - Fixed first column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm creating a schedule table with events and hours, so I need to fix the first column when table is horizontally scrolling. This will help users to see the hour of the event more easily. I'm using Bootstrap 4. Screenshot of the table: http://prntscr.com/japkbc.

Best Regards

Comment: have you tried using DataTables? ref: https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/

Comment: Yes, I did. It changed all the table, made it smaller and added search bar - things that I don't need.

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you

Comment: Use can remove search bar, set the column width with DATATABLES

Comment: @GhoSTBG please add code

Comment: @HarmandoTaufikGemilang the problem with datatables is that it doesnt support fixed columns and fixed header at the same time which is something I am looking for

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
th
{
background-color:black;
color:white;
}
th:first-child, td:first-child
{
  position:sticky;
  left:0px;
 
}
 td:first-child
 {
  background-color:grey;
 }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
     <th>TIME</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11:40   </td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
     <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td> 
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
     <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11:40   </td>
     <td>Maria Anders</td>
     <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
     <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11:40   </td>
     <td>Maria Anders</td>
     <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
     <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>11:40   </td>
     <td>Maria Anders</td>
     <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
     <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11:40   </td>
     <td>Maria Anders</td>
     <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
     <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11:40   </td>
     <td>Maria Anders</td>
     <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
     <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: upvoted, how do you manage the onscroll event if you also need a fixed header in addition to a fixed column, most solutions i have seen replicate a div with data from the original header and then offset it on scroll, what happens to scroll left and right in that scenario? also position sticky is a bad idea, doesnt seem like a widely supported thing